# Using python selenium to click and download files

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i'm currently trying to automate the task of clicking different download links from this website:
**https://www.theice.com/clear-us/risk-management#margin-rates**

in this page, i first have to click the "Download ICE Risk Model array files" header which gives me 2 dropdowns from which i want to first click the "Final" link which downloads a csv file for each month of each available year.

Currently, both the dropdowns change due to hidden dropdown menus above, i have first tried to make them visible which was successful as well as changing year in it using selenium click,

The problem arising is that i'm not able to click the "Final" link in the csv section but it just clicks the "
Intercontinental Exchange"
button in the footer and navigates to a new page.

Is there anyway to get this task done ?

As well as is it possible to change the download location to the current directory where the .py script is ?

This is the python code so far, i currently removed the headless part to see what's going on :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import os

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
chrome_path = which("chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1366, 768)

driver.get("https://www.theice.com/clear-us/risk-management#margin-rates")

main_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h4[@class="collapsible-section-header"]')
main_button.click()
time.sleep(5)

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('icus-ice-form-year').style.display = 'block';")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('icus-ice-form-month').style.display = 'block';")
time.sleep(1)

dropdown_1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="icus-ice-form-year"]'))
dropdown_2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="icus-ice-form-year"]'))
main_table_div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="icus-ice-riskarraytable"]')

main_table = main_table_div.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@class="table table-data"]')

for opt in dropdown_1.options:
    
    
    opt.click()
    for opt2 in dropdown_2.options:
        opt2.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        download_links_1 = main_table.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="table-partitioned"]')
        for dow in download_links_1:
            try:
                temp_dow = dow.find_element_by_xpath('//a')

                temp_dow.click()

                time.sleep(4)

            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should switch the downloads to the current working directory and print all the early csvs. change '//*[@id="icus-ice-riskarraytable"]/table/tbody/tr[{0}]/td[2]/a' to '//*[@id="icus-ice-riskarraytable"]/table/tbody/tr[{0}]/td[3]/a' for the other final csv.

```
options = Options()
currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": currentDirectory,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False
}
#print(currentDirectory)
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver.get("https://www.theice.com/clear-us/risk-management#margin-rates")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
main_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h4[@class="collapsible-section-header"]')
main_button.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('icus-ice-form-year').style.display = 'block';")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('icus-ice-form-month').style.display = 'block';")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
drop1length=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//select[@id="icus-ice-form-year"]/option'))
#print(drop1length)
for i in range(1,drop1length-1):
    drop1=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="icus-ice-form-year"]'))
    drop1.select_by_index(i)
    drop2length=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//select[@id="icus-ice-form-month"]/option'))
    #print(drop2length)
    for j in range(1,drop2length-1):
        drop2=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="icus-ice-form-month"]'))
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        drop2.select_by_index(j)
        download_links_length = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="icus-ice-riskarraytable"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a'))
        #print(download_links_length)
        for dow in range(1,download_links_length-1):
            try:
                element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="icus-ice-riskarraytable"]/table/tbody/tr[{0}]/td[2]/a'.format(str(dow)))
                driver.implicitly_wait(5)
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
              
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Import these

```
import os
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Comment: i ran the code, it was able to show the hidden dropdowns, then the dates changed to 2019 December, and then this error came, :

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ice_clear_us2.py", line 43, in <module>
    drop2.select_by_index(j)
  File "C:\Users\faisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 103, in select_by_index
    raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with index %d" % index)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with index 1`

Comment: Oh I had some waits before let me add.